# How to combine the numeric values of all columns with a similar second text field

Tags: google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets like this:

```
Hours | Project
2.5     ABC
0.5     DEF
1.0     ABC
0.25    GHI
1.5     DEF
```

I would like to create an output that shows me all combined hour values on a per-project basis, so something like:

```
Hours combined | Project
3.5              ABC
2.0              DEF
0.25             GHI
```

This seems a rather simple logic, but I don't even know what exactly to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that will be with QUERY(). Assuming your data is in A6:B11, to obtain the result you want use the following formula:

```
=query(A6:B11, "select B, sum(A) group by B", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! I added in an additional `is not null` check to not sum hours that don't have a project, other than that it works perfect. Leaving the -1 for headers away makes more sense on my data.